# d3: replace a number value with text on x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a multiline chart in d3 v3 reusing the code taken mainly from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/asielen/44ffca2877d0132572cb) since I'm a begginner in js and it seemed to fit my needs the most.

However, what I do have now on my x axis are IDs and I would like to have there the text values (NAME from data shown below).

This is the code concerning x axis:

```
chartObj.formatAsNumber = d3.format(".0f"); // since now ID are represented as numbers

chartObj.xFormatter = chartObj.formatAsNumber; //TODO as text value

chartObj.bisect = d3.bisector(chartObj.xFunct).left; // used for tooltip

chartObj.xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, chartObj.width]).domain(d3.extent(chartObj.data, chartObj.xFunct));
   // chartObj.xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().range([0, chartObj.width]).domain(dataset.map(function(d) { return d."NAME"; })); // (?)

chartObj.xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(chartObj.xScale).orient("bottom").tickFormat(chartObj.xFormatter);

chartObj.svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + chartObj.height + ")").call(chartObj.xAxis).append("text").attr("class", "label").attr("x", chartObj.width / 2).attr("y", 30).style("text-anchor", "middle").text(chartObj.xAxisLabel);
```

And the function for mousemove:

```
function mousemove() {
            var x0 = chartObj.xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]), i = chartObj.bisect(dataset, x0, 1), d0 = chartObj.data[i - 1], d1 = chartObj.data[i];

            try {
                var d = x0 - chartObj.xFunct(d0) > chartObj.xFunct(d1) - x0 ? d1 : d0;
            } catch (e) { return;}
            minY = chartObj.height;
            for (var y  in yObjs) {
                yObjs[y].tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + chartObj.xScale(chartObj.xFunct(d)) + "," + chartObj.yScale(yObjs[y].yFunct(d)) + ")");
                yObjs[y].tooltip.select("text").text(chartObj.yFormatter(yObjs[y].yFunct(d)));
                minY = Math.min(minY, chartObj.yScale(yObjs[y].yFunct(d)));
            }
            focus.select(".focus.line").attr("transform", "translate(" + chartObj.xScale(chartObj.xFunct(d)) + ")").attr("y1", minY);
        }
```

And the data I use looks like this:

```
[{"ID":"2","NAME":"version:BA01","min":"44.8","max":"44.8"},{"ID":"6","NAME":"version:BA10","min":"44.7","max":"44.9"},{"ID":"7","NAME":"version:BA21","min":"45.0","max":"45.1"},{"ID":"28","NAME":"version:BA25","min":"44.9","max":"44.9"}]
```

I would really appreciate if you could possibly explain how to replace ID (number) with NAME (text) value on the x axis not loosing the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Change chartObj.xFormatter = chartObj.formatAsNumber; to chartObj.xFormatter = chartObj. NAME; 
It will be easier if you can produce a JSFiddle and share the link if the solution doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't. I tried to make the fiddle work but there must be an error yet.
http://jsfiddle.net/g0qeba6o/1/

Comment: Please render the graph in JSFiddle

Comment: What do you mean by render the graph? Because the function is used (last line)

Comment: The graph is not rendering in JSFiddle, will it be okay for you if I refer to any example and show you how to change the labels on XAxis?

Comment: I will be grateful for any kind of help

Comment: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/RamNlSYr0IqHfSbY?open=lib%2Fscript.js -- you can check how the data should be , and play around with this graph . If you want any further modification on this graph , please let me know. Thanks .

Comment: The thing is that I need to have version* on the x axis (now the values are 2,4,6,etc and I need only four: version:BA01 etc.) and in the legend there should be max and min. Therefore, there are two (not four) series of data (only for max and min)